How to find rows in a table that have no references left?
I have this user-agents-table in my db:
CREATE TABLE user_agents (
  pk bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_agent TEXT NOT NULL,
  user_agent_hash BINARY(16) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pk),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_as_cs;

And this table is referenced by several other tables by foreign-key-constraints.
Now I want to clean-up all user-agents that aren't referenced anymore.
Of course I can do this:
SELECT pk
FROM user_agents ua
  LEFT JOIN table_1 t1 ON ua.pk = t1.user_agent_fk
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON ua.pk = t2.user_agent_fk
  LEFT JOIN table_3 t3 ON ua.pk = t3.user_agent_fk
  LEFT JOIN table_4 t4 ON ua.pk = t4.user_agent_fk
WHERE t1.pk IS NULL
  AND t2.pk IS NULL
  AND t3.pk IS NULL
  AND t4.pk IS NULL;

But this looks pretty ugly and if someone adds table_5, that also references the user-agent-table, he also has to remember to add the new table to the clean-up-job.
So I'm searching for an easy way to ask my db: Find all entries of the table user_agents that have no foreign-key-references anymore (without listing the tables explicitly)

Are the references constrained by foreign key constraints?

Yes, they all look like this: CONSTRAINT usfk FOREIGN KEY (user_agent_fk) REFERENCES user_agents (pk) ON DELETE SET NULL

The fact that they use ON DELETE SET NULL will make the answer from Akina not work the way you want. It will delete all your rows.

Add ON DELETE RESTRICT to all FOREIGN KEY definitions then use simple DELETE IGNORE.
CREATE TABLE main (id INT PRIMARY KEY)
SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4;
CREATE TABLE slave1 (id INT, FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES main (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT);
INSERT INTO slave1 SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 2;
CREATE TABLE slave2 (id INT, FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES main (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT);
INSERT INTO slave2 SELECT 2 id UNION SELECT 4;
SELECT * FROM main;




id
remarks




1
referenced from slave1


2
referenced from slave1 and slave2


3
have no references, should be deleted


4
referenced from slave2



DELETE IGNORE FROM main;
SELECT * FROM main;




id




1


2


4



fiddle

changing the reference-option from ON DELETE SET NULL to ON DELETE RESTRICT is a great idea! Thank you!
